# What does ても mean here?

Tags: grammar, words

> 女性は「火葬できる日を聞くと、いちばん早くても亡くなってから11日あとでした。

[From this NHK easy article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10014108761000/k10014108761000.html)

What is the meaning of ても here? Is it like "Even the earliest (date).."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of 〜ても in the phrase「でも普通どおりにやっても面白くないから…」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39894/usage-of-%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82-in-the-phrase-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e6%99%ae%e9%80%9a%e3%81%a9%e3%81%8a%e3%82%8a%e3%81%ab%e3%82%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e9%9d%a2%e7%99%bd%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it like "Even the earliest (date).."

Yes it is. Except it's not 早く + ても, but 早くて + も. The 早くて is the te-form of 早い, and も is just the particle も meaning "also, even" as in 私**も**人間です(I'm **also** a human) or 彼**も**できない(**Even** he cannot do it).

A te-form is needed when you connect a clause to は or も to discuss it as the topic, as seen in the following examples, normal 終止形 would not work and the te-form is required.

(Copied from my previous answers)

> 全部食べ**る**もいい ❌ 全部食べ**て**もいい　⭕️
> 行かな**い**はダメ ❌　行かな**くて**はダメ ⭕️

Therefore:

> いちばん早**い**も亡くなって... ❌
> いちばん早**くて**も亡くなって... ⭕️

Comment: hmm I think verb teform + も is not equivalent to noun + も as the answer seems to imply.
彼も -> 食べるのも /
彼でも -> 食べても

Comment: @FelipeChavesdeOliveira I'm not saying it's equivalent, I'm only saying that it's the same も

Comment: The first paragraph's examples make it seem like it. 
Making a correlation of noun + も with verb + ても, could even make one think that 食べてができない is a correct structure. That is why 彼でもできない would be a better comparison. 

"A te-form is needed when you connect a clause to は or も to discuss it as the topic" This also sounds half-correct to me, since there are other ways to do it as well. The most common way to introduce a verb as a topic is nominalizing it with の or こと, right?!

Comment: @FelipeChavesdeOliveira Yep, but if you use の or こと then the structure becomes noun+は/も, the grammatical structure is no longer verb+は/も. Also to explain myself more clearly, the first examples only serve to show that the も in OP's question is simply the も-particle, and that ても is not a single word but it should be 早くて + particle も.